# How much data can rails parameter pass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I'm trying to make a post request to server along with a massive string of data to be placed into the database. I noticed that it was cut off at a certain point (about 440K of data in that one variable). I'm just wondering how much data can Rails hold in the parameter to pass to the server?

Thanks.

Comment: Is passing that much data as a post request a good practice?

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit imposed by rails on the size of posted data (or data passed in the URL)

Other intermediaries may have have limits however, for example nginx has a `client_max_body_size`. Also check your database settings: if your data is longer than the maximum length of the corresponding column some databases will silently truncate (others will raise an error). I'd start by checking in your controller that the parameters have the expected length.